# Why is my private member displayed as another type than it is defined as?

Tags: c++, vector, include, header-files

I'm currently working on a project in C++ and I'm just not allowed to push_back on my vector (compile error).

The method where everything seems to go wrong looks like this:

```
DetectionResult DetectionManager::Update(DetectionInput& input) const
{
    std::vector<DetectionResultUnfiltered> results;
    results.reserve(m_detectionModels.size());

    for (auto& detectionModel : m_detectionModels)
    (
        std::future<void> future = std::async(std::launch::async, UpdateDetectionModelAsynchronously, detectionModel, &results, &input);
        m_futures.push_back(future); // <-- Compile error only on this line
    )
}
```

I think it is rather unimportant what exactly the other called method does and how those types are structured exactly. The only important thing should be that the field `m_futures` is of the type `std::vector<std::future<void>>`.

Even when hovering the `m_futures` in Visual Studio within that method, it clearly shows me that it is of the correct type `(field) std::vector<std::future<void>> DetectionManager::m_futures`.

But still the .push_back() call is underlined in red, and when hovered it shows the following error: `no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Ty=std::future<void>, _Alloc=std::allocator<std::future<void>>]" matches the argument list and object (the object has type qualifiers that prevent a match) - argument types are: (std::future<void>) - object type is: const std::vector<std::future<void>, std::allocator<std::future<void>>>`

I'm pretty sure my vector is not really handled as a vector in this current case, because when auto completing the method calls on my vector I don't get even a suggestion for .push_back() or .emplace_back() or something like this. I think it is handled as an object of a type I imported from another library (opencv::mat or something like that), because at some point it was even shown like that when hovered.

And by the way,
the method call is not shown as an error when I do this:
`(static_cast<std::vector<std::future<void>>>(m_futures)).push_back(future);`
so by explicitly casting it to a vector it seems to work again.

I just don't know exactly what happens here. I've traced down and commented some includes to make sure nothing weird was included. And while doing that I figured out that I don't get any errors highlighted within the DetectionManager.h even when commenting out the #include  (Even if not including ANYTHING in the .h at all, only the #include  is needed when working with that type).

It doesn't even work on other vectors as well, so when implementing an example vector which only holds bools, I don't need to include the  and everything looks right according to Visual Studio, which is weird enough since I didn't include  or  which I'm using as well.

Does anyone have any idea what it might be? Or how to track down this error?

Big thanks in advance!

Comment: Your method is marked const. Should it be? did you make m_futures mutable? otherwise you wont be able to modify the vector in any way. Generally speaking a method called 'Update' that is also marked const seems weird to me. Typically updates change things but const says you wont... its a bit of a contradiction

Comment: Oh wow, thanks a lot.

Yeah, the behaviour changed inbetween. Of course I'm not allowed to change the vector in a const method. Back then it was more like a "Calculate" and thus really was const. Now we restructured a bit of the code and the const was just a leftover from the old design.

Comment: @Borgleader If you want to, you can repost this comment as an answer, then I can mark it as the correct answer to my problem. I can't do that on a comment.

Answer (score 0):

As Borgleader correctly pointed out, the method was marked as const - but when pushing back, I am modifying the class field which is obviously not allowed.

The const was a leftover from an older design I just reworked and thus I completely forgot about it.
That paired with some other weird errors I had before (like the field being shown as a complete different type from some library I imported even though it was clearly declared as a vector) didn't help.

I still don't quite understand why my project is compiling when not including  or  within the header file at all even when I declare fields with those types, but at least that's not stopping me from building and running the program.